# Request application/x-www-form-urlencoded usando Volley

Tags: android, volley

Bom dia pessoal, estou tentando fazer uma integração com web_services de um parceiro, por php tudo funcionou corretamente agora quero implementar diretamente no Android usando volley porém estou recebendo erro de autenticação, segue abaixo meu código:

```
 RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            String url = url;
            JsonObjectRequest jReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject2) {

                            try {
                                if (jsonObject2 != null) {
                                    lista.add(jsonObject2.toString());
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                } else {
                                    Log.i("MaintActivity", jsonObject2.toString());
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.i("MaintActivity", e.getMessage().toString());
                            }


                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    if (volleyError != null) {
                        Log.i("MaintActivity", volleyError.getMessage().toString());
                    }

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("ws_key",ws_key);
                    params.put("ws_user",ws_user);
                    params.put("username",username);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }


            };


            jReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                            5000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                    )
            );
            rq.add(jReq);
```

Cabe destacar que fazendo debug, o código só está entrando no método getHeaders e não passa pelo getParams, alguém tem uma ideia?

Agradeço.

Comment: Pode postar o erro?

Comment: Igor, na verdade o erro é retornado pelo web_service do cliente, me retorna um json :  
{"result":false,"error_message":"Authentication error!"}
Não tenho erros de código, de compilação etc....é erro na autenticação..ou seja, os dados de key, user e username não estão chegando no webservice parece. 
Como falei no final , o debug não passa pela função getParams então parece que não está incluindo os dados na requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `JsonObjectRequest` não invoca o método `getParams`!

Aconselho que use o `StringRequest` no lugar dele ficando assim:

```
StringRequest jReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
                  try {
                      JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(response);
                      if (jsonObject2 != null) {

                         lista.add(jsonObject2.toString());
                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      } else {
                          Log.i("MaintActivity", jsonObject2.toString());
                      }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("MaintActivity", e.getMessage().toString());
                   }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            if (volleyError != null) {
                                Log.i("MaintActivity", volleyError.getMessage().toString());
                            }
                     }
            }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("ws_key",ws_key);
                params.put("ws_user",ws_user);
                params.put("username",username);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }


        };
```

Outro fato que notei no seu código e que você está indicando no `JsonObjectRequest` que a passagem de parâmetros será por `GET` mude para `Request.Method.POST` agora no `StringRequest`!

Comment: Certo Igor, fiz uma String request.
Foi resolvido pelo cliente no final, a parte de autenticação da outra ponta foi arrumada e  consegui passar os dados na url ( a pedidos deles).
Obrigado.

Comment: @MarceloLópez De nada estamos aqui para nos ajudarmos!